# Moving built-in gradle tasks work to doLast/built-in tasks shourtcuts

Tags: gradle

I want to create a simple sync task that slightly change it behaviour depending on build type (e.g. debug/release) and I use boolean variable 'dummy' decrared in gradle.taskGraph.whenReady:

```
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {taskGraph ->
  dummy = false
  if (taskGraph.hasTask(':dummybuild')) {
    dummy = true
  }
}
```

The problem is that task configured by the following way has configuration scope, i.e. before whenReady so it doesn't have access to the 'dummy' variable:

```
task copySkins(type: Sync) {
  from skinsFrom
  into skinsInto
  rename skinsRename
  exclude symbianExclude
  if (!dummy) exclude dummyExclude
}
```

Right now I'm using this workaround

```
task copySkins {
  inputs.dir skinsFrom
  outputs.dir skinsInto

  doLast {
    task skins(type: Sync) {
      from skinsFrom
      into skinsInto
      rename skinsRename
      exclude symbianExclude
      if (!dummy) exclude dummyExclude
    }
    skins.execute()
  }
}
```

Is it possible to

1. detect/setup some build properties in some other place except whenReady
2. move sync task work to doLast
3. or at least have some shortcut for sync task (.execute() looks quite ugly)

Answer (score 2):

1) `whenReady` event allows user to access fully-initialized task graph: all initialization is finished and tasks are ready to run. The only situation, when you need to detect/setup build properties here, is when you need to introspect current build setup.
If you do not need this information, you can place your initialization anywhere in your build script. At the very end, it is nothing but groovy script.

```
    apply plugin: 'java'
    def now = new Date()
    compileJava.doFirst {
      println "It is ${now}. We are starting to compile"
    }
```

2) You can not move sync task work to doLast. But you can always add your actions to doFirst ;) I think, this should work:

```
task copySkins(type: Sync) {
  from skinsFrom
  into skinsInto
  rename skinsRename
  exclude symbianExclude

  doFirst {
    if (!dummy) exclude dummyExclude
  }
}
```

3) With all said before, missing sync task shortcut should not be that painfull

Comment: 1) it seems that gradle DAG is completely useless and even bad for configuring buit-in tasks like sync: a) whenReady is called only after configuration phase and sync is executed during it b) this makes impossible multi build configs like debug+release. I'll post separate question regrading this to the gradle-user ML

2) this doesn't work - task is executed in configuration phase, doFirst is executed in 'run' phase